# Possible to launch the Google Assistant from my own Xamerin Android application?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Is it possible to launch the Google Assistant from my own Xamerin Android application instaed of long press the home button? I have done some research and there are plenty of examples where the Google Assistant can call your own application but not the way around. Is Google allowing users to launch the Assistant in other ways than speech and the home button?

Answer (score 0):

Just start its activity `com.google.android.apps.googleassistant/.AssistantActivity`
I believe something like below should do the trick

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.googleassistant");
i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.googleassistant.AssistantActivity");
startActivity(i);
```